# String value found, but an integer is required

Tags: javascript, json, forms

For a long time I have been using a *vanilla* piece of Javascript like:

```
<form onsubmit="return jsonpost(this);" method=POST action=/validate/>
    <label>Firstname: <input required name=firstName></label>
    <label>Lastname: <input required name=lastName></label>
    <label>Age: <input name=age type=number></label>
    <input type=submit>
<form>

<script>
function jsonpost(jsonpostform) {

    // collect the jsonpostform data while iterating over the inputs
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonpostform.length; i++) {
        var input = jsonpostform[i];
        if (input.name && input.value) {
            data[input.name] = input.value;
        }
    }

    // construct an HTTP request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(jsonpostform.method, jsonpostform.action);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    // send the collected data as JSON
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    return false;
}
</script>
```

To serialise the form and POST it over XMLHttpRequest. However I've noticed this code doesn't handle [type=number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) correctly. Is there a better minimal pattern?

Comment: please add some data to highlight your problem.

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't handle numbers correctly" means?

Comment: Input values becomes strings, but input of type number should be treated as an integer.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you [_provide code people can use to reproduce the problem_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rayon Dabre has pointed, the `type=number` input is still a string. You can collect the data from the form in a more smart way. For instance:

```
// Map of type -> function that converts the value
// Add more converters if you need'em
var type2converter = {number: Number}  

// Converter that does not do anything for fallback
var id = function (x) { return x } 

function getFormData(form) {

    var data = {}
    var converter
    var input

    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        input = form[i]

        if (input.name && input.value) {
            // Get the function that converts the data, or fallback to "dummy-converter"
            converter = converters[input.type] || id
            data[input.name] = converter(input.value)
        }
    }

    return data
}
```

This way the returned object will have the type you defined in the HTML. It must be validated on the server though.

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code, though was hoping to see a fully worked example. Curious to know how other JS frameworks handle this. Is it any easier?

Answer (score 2):

> [`type=number`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)), *The input element represents a control for setting the element's value to a **string representing a number***

So the value of the `type="Number"` will be a string which will be *valid floating-point number* if converted(`Number(YOUR_VALUE)`)

Comment: Ok, so where should the conversion happen in order to meet a schema like http://s.natalian.org/2016-04-18/schema.json ??

Comment: Which `validator` you are applying ? You must test it for `valid-floating-number`...

Comment: Generic json schema validator

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the call to retrieve the value in parseInt() - e.g.

```
parseInt(input.value);
```

This will retrieve an Integer representation of the value in the form. You'd probably want some sanity checking on it though to ensure that it is an int and won't break things as well though.

Comment: I know how to make an integer cast. ;) Was hoping to see a complete minimal serialisation of a form to test for number input types.